# Segmentation Fault after creating PyQGIS standalone application the second time even after exitQgis() - Debian

Tags: docker, debian, qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to create several .qgs project files to be served at a later time by an instance of qgis Server.
To this end I need to start a new PyQGIS application several times upon request. The application runs **smoothly the first time** it is called, but if I try to run it a **second time** I get a Segmentation Fault error.

Here is an example code that triggers the problem:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
import os

os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"

for i in range(2):
    print(f'Iteration number {i}')

    print('\tSet prefix path')
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', False)    
    
    print('\tInstantiating application')
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
    
    print('\tInitializing application')
    qgs.initQgis()
    
    print('\tExiting')
    qgs.exitQgis()
```

When executed, I get this output:

```
Iteration number 0
        Set prefix path
        Instantiating application
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
        Initializing application
        Exiting
Iteration number 1
        Set prefix path
        Instantiating application
        Initializing application
Segmentation fault
```

Something similar happens if I enclose the content of the loop inside a function and call it multiple times. In this case the segmentation fault happens upon calling `qgs.exitQgis()` the second time (and any vector or raster layers added before that would be invalid).

Maybe the problem is that for some reason `qgs.exitQgis()` is not really cleaning up before exit?

The code is running on a Python:3.9 docker container that comes with Debian Bullseye.
Qgis has been installed following the instruction from the QGIS docs:
https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. QGIS version is QGIS 3.22.3-Białowieża 'Białowieża'.

To prevent an import error when loading `qgis.core` I had to set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was fixed in QGIS ver. 3.24 Tisler. Now qgs.exitQgis() can be called in a loop without triggering a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Following a suggestion of one comment found on this post:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250933/using-exitqgis-in-pyqgis,
I substituted `qgs.exitQgis()` with `qgs.exit()` and now the app can be instantiated again any number of times without crashing.

It is still not clear what causes the segmentation fault, but at least I found this workaround.